# Mysterious "Different batch numbers for input features" error in Keras model exported to CoreML

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling, keras, coreml

I've bumped into an error in a Keras model exported to CoreML and I haven't been able to figure out where it is coming from or what is causing it. I am working with Xcode 9 + MacOS 10.13.5 High Sierra + Keras 2.1.5. I was not able to determine the CoreML version.

The model is an LSTM ("long short term memory") model created in Keras and exported to CoreML. I've successfully linked the model into my iOS app. However when I run the app, I get the following error when trying to generate a prediction from the LSTM.

```
2018-07-11 11:47:30.159116-0700 mymlmodelapp[32544:191635] [coreml] Different batch numbers for input features.
2018-07-11 11:47:30.159409-0700 mymlmodelapp[32544:191635] [coreml] Failure in resetSizes.
```

I'm really at a loss at this point. I can't figure out from where the error originates. I tried to set a breakpoint in Xcode to break on Swift errors but the breakpoint is not triggered. I can inspect the error instance by setting a breakpoint at the point at which the error is caught, but I don't see how to get the stack trace for the point at which the error was thrown.

I can't find any documentation about it in CoreML, Keras or Tensorflow. Also I can't find that string in the Keras or Tensorflow source code, or in the CoreML libraries (binaries only, I was not able to find the source code, if you know how to get it, I would be very interested).

So to some extent this is about CoreML + Keras but also this is just a general question about how to figure out, in Xcode, from where errors are coming.

Here's the code in question. `Foo_Bar` is the name of the input which was assigned in Keras. The intent is to parse a text field into value which are the input, then give the input to LSTM, get the output, and paste the output into another text field.

```
@IBAction func mybuttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let s: String? = myinput.text
    if (s != nil && s!.count > 0) {
        guard let input_data = try? MLMultiArray(shape:[1, 4, 2], dataType:.double) else {
            fatalError("Unexpected runtime error. MLMultiArray")
        }

        let w = s!.split(separator: " ")
        let x = w.map { s1 in Double(s1) }

        var x8 = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: 8)
        for i in 0..<(x.count > 8 ? 8 : x.count) {
            if x[i] != nil {
                x8[i] = x[i]!
            }
        }
        for i in 0..<8 {
            input_data[i] = NSNumber(value: x8[i])
        }

        let mymodel = myLSTM_regressionModel_sos06252018 ()
        do {
            let lstm_input = myLSTM_regressionModel_sos06252018Input (Foo_Bar: input_data)
            let output_data = try mymodel.prediction (input: lstm_input)
            let y = output_data.featureValue (for: "Predictions")
            let z = y?.multiArrayValue
            myoutput.text = String(z!.count)
        }
        catch {
            myoutput.text = "OOPS: \(error)"
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT 2018-07-27: I found that the example works by change `shape:[1, 4, 2]` to `shape:[4, 1, 2]`. That doesn't make any sense to me, but as they say, there's no arguing with success. I tried several other permutations which failed.

Comment: Was it a `stateful=True` model?

Comment: Was it defined with explicit `batch_input_shape` or `batch_shape`?

Comment: The HDF5 file contained in the coremltools output says `"stateful": false`. That same file says `"batch_input_shape": [null, 4, 2]`. Hmm, I see that's not the same as what I put for the shape. I wonder if I can specify [nil, 4, 2] instead of [1, 4, 2]; I will try it at least.

Comment: Changing `shape:[1, 4, 2]` to `shape:[nil, 4, 2]` causes an error since each element of `shape` needs to be NSNumber. I guess that's not surprising.

Comment: Hi Robert. I see you found a solution. Did it give the expected result? Is it predicting correctly, in other words? I ran into the same problem and putting the sequence length first (4) and then the batch size (1) seems to make the model run, but the result isn't very good. Not sure if that's because of my model or because I need to change around other things to fit the reordering.

Comment: @MScottWaller For one-step predictions with the LSTM (i.e., no iterating the predictions) the result I get in Swift + CoreML is the same as the result in Python + Keras. Note that the LSTM model has what appear to be automatically generated inputs and outputs which, I believe, are supposed to be used if one is iterating to make multi-step predictions. Perhaps that's something to look at if you are getting different results in Swift vs Python.